# on the derivation of the relaxation quantum dynamics

Tags: quantum-mechanics, newtonian-mechanics

I am reading the book  by ULI WURFEL. In the second chapter, the author try to derive an equation of a quantum system dynamics under the influence of its environment, which can cause dissipation and dephasing of the system. I am following the derivation in this book, however, i got some problem, and i get stuck at some place, i really hope some help from you.

I do not know how to write equations here, so i made two pictures. In the first picture there is the derivation by the author of the book.
In the second picture, it is my try to get the final formula, and where i got stuck. It is very appreciated if anyone could give me some hints on my problem.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

First of all, notice that the final expression does use $\rho_I(\tau)$, so it is not a good idea to deconstruct it while evaluating your integrand. Second, the crucial observation is that 
$$
G_0(t){\hat z} \equiv e^{-iG_0 t} {\hat z} = e^{-i(H_S+H_B)t} \;{\hat z}\; e^{i(H_S+H_B)t}
$$
This is easily verified by comparing the time derivatives of the two forms.

Taking into account that $e^{-i H_B t} \rho_B e^{i H_B t} = \rho_B$ and with some algebra, this gives for the integrand of interest,
$$
Tr_B\left( V(t) V(\tau) \rho_I(\tau) \otimes \rho_B \right) = Tr_B\left( G_0(-t)L_{SB} G_0(t-\tau) L_{SB} G_0(\tau) \rho_I(\tau) \otimes \rho_B \right) =\\
=  Tr_B\left( G_0(-t)L_{SB} G_0(t-\tau) \left[ \sum_n{{\hat S}_n {\hat q}_n}, \;e^{-i H_S \tau} \rho_I(\tau) e^{i H_S \tau} \otimes \rho_B \right] \right) = \\
= Tr_B\left( G_0(-t)L_{SB}  \sum_n{ e^{-i H_S t} {\hat S}_n(-\tau) \rho_I(\tau) e^{i H_S t} \otimes {\hat q}_n(t-\tau) \rho_B}\right) -\\
- Tr_B \left( G_0(-t)L_{SB}  \sum_n{ e^{-iH_S t} \rho_I(\tau) {\hat S}_n(-\tau) e^{i H_S t} \otimes \rho_B {\hat q}_n(t-\tau)} \right) 
$$
etc. I leave it to you to finish the rest.